# Create copy of self in base destructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to write a family of classes that create copies of themselves under certain conditions when getting destructed. Please see the code below

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool destruct = false;

class Base;
Base* copy;

class Base {
public:

virtual ~Base() {
    if (!destruct) {
        destruct = true;
        copy = nullptr; /* How to modify this line? */
        std::cout << "Copying" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Destructing" << std::endl;
    }
}

};

class Derived : public Base {
public:

Derived(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}

std::string name;

};

int main() {
    { Derived d("hello"); }

    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Derived*>(copy)->name << std::endl;

    delete copy;

    return 0;
}
```

How do I need to change the line `copy = nullptr;` such that it performs a full copy of `this` and the output becomes as shown below?

```
Copying
hello
Destructing
```

Comment: *Why* do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @user207421 I want to write a library of container classes that behave like in Python. `Base` shall be the common base class for classes whose instances can be stored in the containers. In particular, I want that if an instance of a class inheriting from `Base` is created in block scope and added to one of those containers, a copy of the object shall be created on the heap if the object goes out of scope so that the reference in the container is still valid. That is, I want the container to store references and not copies when adding elements.

Comment: I here assumed that the container is defined in an outer scope, so that it still persists even though the object added to it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

By the time the base destructor runs, the derived destructor has already run and destroyed information that the copying would need to preserve.

You need to change your approach.